# Knockout ko.toJSON causing SecurityError Permission denied error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to do a ko.toJSON on an observableArray. It was working fine but seems to have stopped working after an update from v.3.3.0 to v.3.4.0. I have not attempted rolling back yet to confirm but I wanted to ask if anyone would have an explanation to this issue.

My observableArray declaration:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray();
```

And my failing function:

```
self.items.subscribe(function (items) {  
localStorage.setItem("Cart", ko.toJSON(items));  
});
```

I am getting the following error message, which I nailed it down to ko.toJSON:

On Chrome:
`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:52519" from accessing a frame with origin "https://staticxx.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Obviously not using any iframes not Facebook.

On Firefox:
`Error: Permission denied to access property "__ko_proto__"`

```
a.Oa    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:41  
a.H @   knockout-3.4.0.js:41  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:56  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
c   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
b   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:55  
a.wc    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:56  
a.toJSON    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:56  
(anonymous function)    @   cart.js:118  
notifySubscribers   @   knockout-3.4.0.js:37  
fa  @   knockout-3.4.0.js:40  
a.la.fn.(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:44  
self.addItem    @   cart.js:101  
(anonymous function)    @   knockout-3.4.0.js:89  
dispatch    @   jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3  
r.handle    @   jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
```

items is an array for CartItem which has some variables, observables, and a computed.

I hope someone has an explanation.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up debugging it using knockout.debug. The error had nothing to do with the error message being returned by Developer Tools. My arguments were not in the right order and my array could not be serialized.
The beauty of JavaScript.